# how to change tab immediately after pop to rootView Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab view with 5 tabs, and each tab are embeded in navigation controller! in tab 1, I enter view controller A, and then entered to viewController B! on a button in B view Controller, I want to pop to root view, and change the tab! and I used this code :

```
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)                  
  self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4
```

but it only pop to root view, and does not changing the tab! 
how can I do both of them?!

Comment: try self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex instead?

Comment: @koropok thank you for your answer,I had to set pop to root view after your suggestion and it's working perfectly! thank you!!

Comment: @koropok I would suggest to add it as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @AhmadF alright, thanks.

Comment: @AzinNilchi could you please accept the answer? FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.

Comment: @AhmadF thanks for your comment and concerns

Comment: It it still working in Swift 5 ? I have tried but was not able to change the selected tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this instead.

```
 self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex
```

Comment: It it still working in Swift 5 ? I have tried but was not able to change the selected tab

Answer (score 0):

you can change selectedIndex and then call popToRootViewController. this do for me.

```
            self?.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
            self?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```